# Correct git workflow on merges/rebase: Should I pull over dirty workspace or local commits?

Tags: git, workflow

Im my company i am encouraged to not push commits to shared repo until im sure they wont make any mess. Then I have two options:

- Make local commits relating to the changes and then rebase/merge the shared repo with it. This way I make a better use of Git and have more controll over the changes i make with several different commits.
- Dont make any local commit but just keep all work in dirty workspace. Then i just pull and resolve issues. Finally i can commit al togheter and push. This way i deal better with Eclipse's slow implementation of Git when it comes to merges/rebase between commits.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Committing your code **step by step** is the best way to ensure you can track your work on a daily basis.
Too often you will make changes to your code that will break something and then you will spend hours just coming back to the previous state where it was still working.

If Eclipse has a slow implementation of git, you should definitely search for another way to use git (through a terminal maybe, depends on the OS you are on)

Comment: Definetly this is the most desirable solution, i think i will move to this. Thanks you for the answer!